# Fatal error: Call to undefined function utf8_substr() Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

My site was working fine from last 2 3 months but now it shows 500 Server error message. Then I saw the `error.log` file it says that

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function utf8_substr() in public_html/catalog/model/tool/image.php on line 11

And the code at the given location is:

```
$new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;
```

Then I thought may be its because of cache and then I cleared the cache and still gets the same error message. I was looking for solution on google and I found few solution like `Clearing cache`, Check if `startup.php` or `utf8.php` is missing or not but file is on the correct place. It is on production env and site is down from last two days.

Please tell me a solution for this problem.

I'm running Opencart version 2.0.3.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. My site was missing `mbstring` extension. `yum install mbstring` wasn't working on my server because it was named `ea-php56-php-mbstring-5.6.26-1.1.2.cpanel.x86_64`. I installed this and my website is working again. If you are also having same problem. Then please ssh into your site and check if mbstring is installed you can check that by running `php -m | grep mbstring` it will not return anything if mbstring is not installed but if extension is installed then it will return mbstring. If `mbstring` is missing then You can run this command `yum search mbstring` it will search extentions with `mbstring` word. Then run this command `yum install NAME_OF_FILE`. Replace NAME_OF_FILE with the name of the `mbstring` file. then follow instruction and once the installation is done. You can cross check if `mbstring` is installed by running `php -m | grep mbstring` command. It was so helpful in my case. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it properly. Thank you tmquang6805

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have installed `mbstring` or `iconv` PHP extension yet. Because this function just load when you installed one of them. This is code for your case https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/helper/utf8.php

Comment: I've replaced entire code but the same error message is keep showing in error.log

Comment: Did you install [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension?

Comment: No I didn't. Because I saw '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' this appears in phpinfo(). Does it mean that extention is already installed ?

Comment: You can check enable mbstring by run this command on console (I run it on linux) `php -m | grep mbstring`.  You can follow [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) for more detail

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ssh into my account and then ran `php -m | grep mbstring` it doesn't show anything. I tried to install mbstring by using this command `yum install php-mbstring` but i get the message `No package php-mbstring available`. May be i'm doing something wrong. I'm sorry and Please correct me.

Comment: I'm running php 5.6 and easy apache 4 (Don't know how to use it). mbstring is not installed if it is because mbstring then please tell me how can I install mbstring. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Install php-mbstring, the only solution