# OpenCart error 500 only for index.php

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, http-status-code-500, opencart2.3

I have been trying to manually migrate OpenCart 2.3.0.2 from Plesk to cPanel and so far it has been working ok. I've uploaded all the files into the file manager's root directory and set both config.php files, the first one under the root directory, and the second one under the admin directory.

Now here goes the problem. Whenever I try to load the page (example.com), I get **error 500**. However, when I try to access the `example.com/admin` page, that one loads successfully. I have managed to log in there a half a dozen times. Also I have created a `info.php` file containing `phpinfo();` and have put the latter file within the root directory. So then I tried to access `example.com/info.php` and that file loaded too. But getting example.com to work always returns error 500. I have even tried reuploading and replacing index.php file, but to no avail.

Please note that I have double and triple checked the `config.php` and `admin/config.php` files for typing errors and I'm pretty confident there are not any.

Any ideas what I should try next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Internal Server Error while trying to access my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179706/getting-internal-server-error-while-trying-to-access-my-site)

Comment: There's no way to debug an error like that without looking at your error logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function utf8\_substr() Opencart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654438/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-utf8-substr-opencart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I hadn't even noticed the existence of error_log file in root directory earlier, but while examining it I stumbled upon:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function utf8_substr() in /home/mydomain/public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/model/tool/image.php on line 11.

Searching online accordingly it returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654438/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-utf8-substr-opencart) SO thread. I followed the instructions given in the last post of the original poster and my problem was solved. Both my website and the /admin work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Error Log for PHP Fatal errors. Also please add this line at the top of your "index.php" ,

```
error_reporting(true);
```

This will show you the Fatal Error you are experiencing.

Hope it helps.